# Python — "list index out of range" error when calling a list index that does exists

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement

When inputting [1, 2, 3] as the parameter for this `function`, I get the `list index out of range` error. I would expect to be able to call nums[1] to get the second index of the `list` — 2 in this example. But I cannot, can anyone help me figure out why?

Thank you

```
def sum2(nums):
  if nums == []:
    return 0
  elif nums <= 1:
    return nums[0]
  elif nums >= 3:
    return nums[0] + nums[1]
```

Comment: I think you need to add the `len` function to the `elif` statements: `elif len(nums) <= 1:`

Comment: I don't see how you get to the indexing operation without python screaming about `nums <= 1`.

Comment: @PoneyUHC The problem is that he didn't specify what he wanted from `nums`

Comment: @XMehdi01 he's talking about inputing [1,2,3], so a list I believe

Comment: @PoneyUHC You did not understand what to compare the list with a number and it is necessary to compare the length of the list with a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the conditions in your `if-elif` statements. You are comparing a `list` (nums) with an integer (1 or 3), which is not valid. You should be checking the length of the `list` instead. Here's the corrected code:

```py
def sum2(nums):
  if len(nums) == 0:
    return 0
  elif len(nums) <= 1:
    return nums[0]
  elif len(nums) >= 3:
    return nums[0] + nums[1]

# input [1, 2, 3]
#len([1, 2, 3]) >= 3 ==> True and nums[0] = 1 + nums[1] = 2 ==> return 3
# output 3
```

I hope the answer is clear enough for you and if you have any questions I am here to help you

Comment: Excellent, of course! Thank you very much for helping to clear this up